# How to sort Hashes of 2-D Arrays (simple example)

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I have following hash with `DIRECTORY_NAMES` as keys, and 2-D arrays as data (`filename` and `size` of the file).

```
$hash{'DIRECTORY_NAME'} = [ 
                            ['filename.txt', 1024]
                          ];
```

It looks something like this:

[image: Valid XHTML]

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
    'DIR_XYZ' => [
                   [
                     'filename_xyz.log',
                     2048 
                   ],
                   [
                     'filename_abc.txt',
                     1024
                   ]
                 ],
    'DIR_ABC' => [
                   [
                     'filename_987.log',
                     4096 
                   ],
                   [
                     'filename_123.txt',
                     2048
                   ]
                 ],
);
$hash{'DIRECTORY_NAME'} = [ 
                            ['filename.txt', 1024]
                          ];

print Dumper \%hash;
```

**My questions:**

1) How to sort data in the `%hash` first by filename then by filesize and no matter of the hash keys? But information about directory name is important, can't be ignored and must be occured on the otutput. So, the output should look like this:

```
filename.txt        1024   (DIRECTORY_NAME)
filename_123.txt    2048   (DIR_ABC)
filename_987.log    4096   (DIR_ABC)
filename_abc.txt    1024   (DIR_XYZ)
filename_xyz.log    2048   (DIR_XYZ)
```

2) How to sort data in the `%hash` first by filesize then by filename and no matter of the hash keys? But information about directory names is important, can't be ignored and must be occured on the otutput. So, the output should look like this:

```
filename.txt        1024   (DIRECTORY_NAME)
filename_abc.txt    1024   (DIR_XYZ)
filename_123.txt    2048   (DIR_ABC)
filename_xyz.log    2048   (DIR_XYZ)
filename_987.log    4096   (DIR_ABC)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You can't sort a hash. The only thing you can sort is a list, so step 1 would be to think about what list you're trying to sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As melpomene said, you can't sort a hash. The only thing you can sort is a list, so step 1 would be to think about what list you're trying to sort.

In this case, the output is a list that contains all the information we need for sorting, so let's start by gathering the info we need to output, then it should be easy to sort.

Specifically, let's generate

```
[ 'DIR_XYZ',        'filename_xyz.log', 2048 ],
[ 'DIR_XYZ',        'filename_abc.txt', 1024 ],
[ 'DIR_ABC',        'filename_987.log', 4096 ],
[ 'DIR_ABC',        'filename_123.txt', 2048 ],
[ 'DIRECTORY_NAME', 'filename.txt',     1024 ],
```

This can be done as follows:

```
my @files = map { [ $_, @{ $hash{$_} } ] } keys(%hash);
```

Sorting the elements of `@files` in the first order:

```
sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1]  ||  $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] } @files
```

Sorting the elements of `@files` in the second order:

```
sort { $a->[2] <=> $b->[2]  ||  $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } @files
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and code, but informations about `DIRECTORY_NAME` (hash keys) are important for me, so I little edited my two questions.

Comment: Adjusted my answer for the changes to the question.